# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Release Management

Tags: jsf-2, jstl

**My xhtml page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <!-- <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  /> -->
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h1>category</h1>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <c:forEach items="#{categoryBean.parentCategoryList}" var="cat">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="#{cat.name}"/>
                        <h:commandButton value="+" type="button" onclick="expand('#{cat.name}');"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:selectManyCheckbox id="#{cat.name}" style="display: none" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategoryList}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.getSubCategoryList(cat.id)}" var="sub" itemLabel="#{sub.name}" itemValue="#{sub.name}"/>
                        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </c:forEach>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result" />
            <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" />
        </h:form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function expand(cat) {
                var name = "form:" + cat;
                alert(name);
                var element = document.getElementById(name);
                if(element.style.display == 'block') {
                  element.value = "-";
                  element.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                  element.value = "+";
                  element.style.display = 'block'
                }
            }
        </script>   
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**My managed bean**

```
package com.gtp.iqp.presentation.managedBeans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.gtp.iqp.business.bo.Category;
import com.gtp.iqp.business.delegate.CategoryDelegate;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
public class CategoryBean extends BaseManagedBean {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDelegate categoryDelegate;
    private List<Category>   parentCategoryList;
    private List<String>     selectedCategoryList;

    public CategoryDelegate getCategoryDelegate() {
        return categoryDelegate;
    }
    public void setCategoryDelegate(CategoryDelegate categoryDelegate) {
        this.categoryDelegate = categoryDelegate;
    }
    public List<Category> getParentCategoryList() {
        parentCategoryList = categoryDelegate.getParentCategories();
        return parentCategoryList;
    }
    public void setParentCategoryList(List<Category> parentCategoryList) {
        this.parentCategoryList = parentCategoryList;
    }
    public List<String> getSelectedCategoryList() {
        return selectedCategoryList;
    }
    public void setSelectedCategoryList(List<String> selectedCategoryList) {
        this.selectedCategoryList = selectedCategoryList;
    }
    public List<Category> getSubCategoryList(long parent) {
        return categoryDelegate.getSubCategories(parent);
    }

}
```

**My problem**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.getSubCategoryList(cat.id)}"/>
```

The selectItems statement above is able to fetch a list from the database. I'm able to see that the managed bean contains the list. However it is not getting displayed once the control is transferred to the xhtml page. I'm seeing the following exception:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.name as name2_1_0_, this_.parent as parent3_1_0_ from category this_ where this_.parent=?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.name as name2_1_0_, this_.parent as parent3_1_0_ from category this_ where this_.parent=?
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.name as name2_1_0_, this_.parent as parent3_1_0_ from category this_ where this_.parent=?
Dec 13, 2013 2:56:06 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
FATAL: JSF1073: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Release Management
Dec 13, 2013 2:56:06 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
FATAL: Release Management
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Release Management
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:592)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:412)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.assignUniqueId(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:176)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:230)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:980)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closer at the class/method names in the top lines of the stack trace, a good library has rather self-explaining class/method names:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Release Management
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:592)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:412)
```

Thus, it happened during setting the `id` of an UI component. The ID is being validated and not considered valid. Indeed, `Release Management` has a space inside which is invalid as per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29):

> Set the component identifier of this UIComponent (if any). Component identifiers must obey the following syntax restrictions:
>
> - Must not be a zero-length String.
> - First character must be a letter or an underscore ('_').
> - Subsequent characters must be a letter, a digit, an underscore ('_'), or a dash ('-').

Spaces in HTML element IDs are by the way also invalid according [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) (you know, JSF is basically just a HTML code generator and it should of course respect the HTML specification):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The culprit is here:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="#{cat.name}" ...>
```

In this particular case, you've basically 2 options to solve it:

1. Use a `<h:dataTable>` instead of `<h:panelGrid><c:forEach>`, it'll receive an autogenerated ID prefixed with row index:

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{categoryBean.parentCategoryList}" var="cat">
       <h:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{cat.name}"/>
           <h:commandButton value="+" type="button" onclick="expand('#{cat.name}');"/>
           <br/>
           <h:selectManyCheckbox id="name" style="display: none" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategoryList}">
               <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.getSubCategoryList(cat.id)}" var="sub" itemLabel="#{sub.name}" itemValue="#{sub.name}"/>
           </h:selectManyCheckbox>
       </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
   ```
2. Use a fixed prefix with an incremental numeric suffix from `<c:forEach varStatus>`:

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="1">
       <c:forEach items="#{categoryBean.parentCategoryList}" var="cat" varStatus="loop">
           <h:panelGroup>
               <h:outputText value="#{cat.name}"/>
               <h:commandButton value="+" type="button" onclick="expand('#{cat.name}');"/>
           </h:panelGroup>
           <h:panelGroup>
               <h:selectManyCheckbox id="name_#{loop.index}" style="display: none" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategoryList}">
                   <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.getSubCategoryList(cat.id)}" var="sub" itemLabel="#{sub.name}" itemValue="#{sub.name}"/>
               </h:selectManyCheckbox>
           </h:panelGroup>
       </c:forEach>
   </h:panelGrid>
   ```

Don't forget to alter the argument of `expand()` JS function accordingly, if necessary.